# Specify tsconfig.json location for Cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress

I'm trying to use Cypress w/ Typescript but Cypress can't find the `tsconfig.json` file I've created for it. I also have a custom directory structure (because I hate when there's a bunch of config files in the root, so I put them in a config directory).

**Project Directory Structure**

```js
/
├── package.json
├── configs/
│   ├── cypress.json
├── src/
│   ├── cypress/
│   │   ├── tsconfig.json
```

**Cypress Open command**

```js
//  package.json

"scripts": {
    "cypress:open": "cypress open --config-file configs/cypress.json"
},
```

In the script above, the `--config-file` flag tells cypress the location of the `cypress.json` config file, which is AWESOME because I can put that file anywhere I want it. However, now I need to instruct Cypress on where to find it's `tsconfig.json` file.

**/configs/cypress.json** (tells Cypress where the `cypress/` directory is)

```
{
  "fixturesFolder": "src/cypress/fixtures",
  "integrationFolder": "src/cypress/integration",
  "pluginsFile": "src/cypress/plugins/index.js",
  "screenshotsFolder": "src/cypress/screenshots",
  "videosFolder": "src/cypress/videos",
  "supportFile": "src/cypress/support/index.js"
}

// is there no option to set tsconfig.json path????
```

The [official documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support.html#Install-TypeScript) says to just put it in the `cypress/` directory. According to the docs, that should be at `/cypress/tsconfig.json`, but in my project it's in `/src/cypress/tsconfig.json`.

Here's the location I've tried to put the `tsconfig.json` file:

```js
/src/cypress/tsconfig.json //Error: "Couldn't find tsconfig.json. tsconfig-paths will be skipped"

/src/tsconfig.json //Error: "Couldn't find tsconfig.json. tsconfig-paths will be skipped"

/cypress/tsconfig.json //Error: "Couldn't find tsconfig.json. tsconfig-paths will be skipped"

/tsconfig.json // Works!! But not where I want this file to live...
```

How can I instruct Cypress on where to look for the tsconf.json file I want it to use? Is there an option in the `cypress.json` config file, or a CLI flag I can use????

I don't want to clutter my project root with miscellaneous config files, and I actually have separate tsconfig files for my project and my test suite. It would be great to set the file path explicitly.

Comment: This seems to be an ongoing issue: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/9048

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While this is not the answer you would like to hear, `tsconfig.json` marks a directory as the root of a typescript project, just like the `package.json` marks a directory as the root of a node.js project. These files help tools like IDEs to understand your project.

In my opinion you should only consider moving `tsconfig.json` when you start to put your `package.json` in some other folder as well.

See also: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: Sadly, I have to admit this might be the best answer.

Answer (score 6):

Refer to the [Cypress Real World App](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/11/introducing-the-cypress-real-world-app/), [a payment application to demonstrate real-world usage of Cypress testing methods, patterns, and workflows](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app).

It is build with create-react-app and TypeScript.  The [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/cypress/tsconfig.json) used for Cypress is located in the [`cypress` directory](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support.html#Configure-tsconfig-json).

It is possible you need to configure a [root tsconfig.json](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/tsconfig.json) and extend it from the [cypress tsconfig.json](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/cypress/tsconfig.json#L2) as done in the RWA.

```
// cypress/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I will investigate this as a possible solution, although the whole point is to avoid having config files (such as tsconfig.json) in the root directory.

Comment: Did any of that work? I think extending cypress tsconfig in root is invalid advice. Whole point of having it separately is ruined by that.

Answer (score 1):

Your `cypress` folder should be in the same directory that contains your `src` folder, not inside the `src` folder.   Also, your `cypress.config.ts` file should be in the same root folder.

Then, you should have a `./cypress/tsconfig.json` that looks like this:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "files": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "../cypress.config.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": false,
    "types": ["cypress", "chai"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is in the types `"types": ["cypress", "chai"]` the chai needed? Where does it came from?

Answer (score 0):

Try if this commands works:

```
//CD to the space you want your .tsconfig 
    cd project_config  
     
  // Create .tsconfig   
     tsc --init  
    
  // Specify were you want to run your tsconfig file from
     tsc -p /path/to/folder/with/tsconfig
```

Comment: could you help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71605624/how-to-generate-only-test-coverage-from-a-specific-folder-with-tests-in-cypress

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved without a root level `tsconfig`. The idea is that we can `cd` into our test folder before running the open command:

With the below file structure your `test` command would look something like this:

```sh
cd ./src/cypress && cypress open --config-file ../../configs/cypress.json
```

```
/
├── package.json
├── configs/
│   ├── cypress.json
├── src/
│   ├── cypress/
│   │   ├── tsconfig.json
```

Just be sure to update your support paths etc in the `cypress.json`, they will now be relative to `src/cypress`

Answer (score 0):

I performed the following steps, and the error message disappeared:

Navigate to the AppData\Roaming\Cypress\cy\production\projects directory.
Locate your project folder within this directory.
Delete the project folder from the directory.
Attempt to open Cypress again and see if the issue is resolved.